# IIS: redirect everything to another URL, except for one Directory

Tags: iis, http, redirect, web

I have an IIS server (IIS 6, Win 2003) that hosts the site http://www.foo.com.

I want any request to http://foo.com (no matter what path/filename is used) to redirect to http://www.bar.org/AwesomePage.html **UNLESS** the request is for http://www.foo.com/specialdir, in which case the HTML files in the local directory specialdir should be used.

The problem I have is once the redirect is set it also affects /specialdir - even if I right click on that directory and select "content should come from ... local directory" that change does not take effect, and the directory still shows as redirecting to http://www.bar.org/AwesomePage.html.  The same thing happens if I try to set individual files to load from the local system instead of redirecting - IIS gives no error, but the change does not take effect and the files still show as being redirected.

How can I set specialdir to override the redirection to the new URL?

Answer (score 1):

oh, yes...

Well, the real solution is to use ISAPI_Rewrite from http://www.isapirewrite.com/ and write a regex for the redirection.

Comment: pls dont multi post like that, this is not a forum. pls read the faq